# Does anyone know the name of this "LookAndFeel"?

Tags: java, swing, themes, look-and-feel

Does anyone know the name of this "LookAndFeel"? or at least know similar one? It's really amazing and I wish I could use it for my program.

http://www.axbo.com/webstart/aXbo.jnlp

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot rather than a link - less scary.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins There.

Comment: Not the same but something like Mac: http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/ Also here are some different skin look and feel theme packs you may like: http://www.javootoo.com/plaf/skinlf/themepacks/index.html

Comment: @Eng.Fouad hard to identify, insubstantial has code source and by this file https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/blob/master/substance/src/test/java/test/Check.java, you can test(is prepared for) all good Java Look and Feel in jar, I'm spent 4hours to switch and compare .... :-) ask author of web site for that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called `syntheticaWhiteVision`.
http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/themes/ (it is the 5<sup>th</sup> on this page)

**How I found this:**

Download and save the `jnlp`. jnlp is a plain text file. Open it and you will see somewhere in the file this:

```
  <resources>
    <jar href="axbo.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/RXTXcomm.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-beanutils.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/infactory-utils.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jcommon-1.0.9.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/swing-components.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/swing-layout-1.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/synthetica.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/syntheticaWhiteVision.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="lib/native_comm.jar"/>
    <j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
      initial-heap-size="32m" max-heap-size="128m"/>
  </resources>
```

**Edit:**

It seems like you have to sign up when you want to download them. Here are the direct links:

- http://www.axbo.com/webstart/lib/synthetica.jar
- http://www.axbo.com/webstart/lib/syntheticaWhiteVision.jar

Comment: Awesome! I download it and I add it to eclipse libraries but when I used it, it gave me this warning: "The type de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: nvm it worked after I download synthetica.jar. Thanks mate :)

Comment: It's not really polite to download their software directly if they want you to register for it: I mean, it's their software and they make the rules.